# I have a leak in my roof and damage to my ceiling. What type of company should I be looking at to repair it?

Tags: leak, roof, contractors

About a month ago, I cleaned out the gutters and removed moss from my roof. About a week later, I noticed a leak in kitchen (near the range hood/exhaust vent), and so I went up and sealed all the flashing, as I didn't see anything obvious with the roof. It's a composite roof (probably 15-20 years old at this point) with a fairly low grade. I was planning to do a more extensive check of the roof once the weather cleared.

However, events intervened. Unusually for Seattle, we have had some very hard rains in the past few weeks. I now have a bulging ceiling near the initial leak, so the leak is worse that I thought, and there is likely ceiling damage. It's moved past my ability to fix in a reasonable amount of time, as I usually go slowly on projects I haven't done before, so I need to hire someone.

What I am trying to figure out is who I should call? I want someone who can fix and/or replace the roof, but also replace any damaged sections of roof/ceiling/joists/etc.

I understand that a roofing company would be able to fix the roof, but I am more concerned about replacing any structural members (joists, venting, etc) and the ceiling. Do roofing companies generally handle that as well, or I am looking for something else?

Comment: pretty close to a duplicate: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/97242/what-should-i-do-about-this-roof-leak?rq=1 - the request for recommendations is also explicitly off topic, other than in chat.

Comment: I'll edit the request for recommendations. I didn't see that one (I didn't search metal roof). However, the post didn't mention structural work (which I hope isn't needed), and was focused on the roof itself.

Comment: As I said, only nearly a duplicate, and no vote to close as a duplicate - but it seemed close enough to perhaps be of use to you.

Comment: No worries, I was only trying to clarify. Thanks for the suggestions!